# Using entity framework, how do you select the datalength of a column plus other column data

Tags: entity-framework, select, datalength

If I have a SQL table X with columns A and B, and I want to select the DATALENGTH of B, as well as column A, how do I do this in a single expression?  For example:

```
var results = dc.X.Select(x => SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.B))
```

will return me results containing a single column equal to B's length.  What does this statement look like if I want to include A in the same result set?  I've tried this, but it won't compile obviously:

```
var results = dc.X.Select(x => new { SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.B), x.A });
```

With the error:

error CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the anonymous type's member names:

```
var results = dc.X.Select(x => 
    new { Length = SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.B), A = x.A });
```