# Get FileStream size (sql server) by mvc app context asp net mvc

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, filestream

I would like if .net (asp.net mvc) provides possibility to get size of FileStream having DbContext. As I did research so far I can:

1) 
`SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH('ColumnName'))FROM Table`

2)

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS [DBNAME], size / 128 AS [Size in MB]
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type = 2;
```

My question is if I can calculate filestream using C#. I have connection to db by DbContext. Can I get size?

Please help me.
BR 
Cenarius

---

UPDATE 10.12.2018

Point of my help was to acquire higher performance, because SUM(DATALENGTH(...) was slow. Thinking about c# I supposed that I may help to speed up query. However the best solution, after reading many articles on google, was to use any how **sys.database_files.**

Thanks for help.

BR

Cenarius

Comment: Why use *LINQ* for such a query? There are no objects involved in this case, just a reporting query. BTW `sys.database_files` is about *database* files, not filestream values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server FILESTREAM Total File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086603/sql-server-filestream-total-file-size)

Comment: If you want to get the size of *one* file use `SELECT DATALENGTH(filestreamcolumn) FROM filestreamtable`. `DATALENGTH('ColumnName')` returns the length of the ASCII string `'ColumnName'`. `SUM(DATALENGTH(filestreamcolumn))` returns the total size of *all* files in the query

Comment: @Cenarious which EF version are you using? EF Core? EF 6? Another one?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Using entity framework, how do you select the datalength of a column plus other column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106616/using-entity-framework-how-do-you-select-the-datalength-of-a-column-plus-other). The answer is to use `SqlFunctions.DataLength`, eg `dc.X.Select(x => 
    new { Length = SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.B), A = x.A });`

Comment: I use EF6, thanks for help, solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many SQL Server built-in functions are available through [SqlFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) in Entity Framework up to 6.2 and [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-2.1) in EF Core 2.1

In EF 6.2, [SqlFunctions.DataLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.datalength?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) can be used to return the size of any field. Eg:

```
var files = myContext.Select(row=>
                       new { 
                            row.Name,
                            Size=SqlFunctions.DataLength(row.File)
                           })
                     .ToArray();
```

The function is *not* availalbe in EF Core unfortunately. An alternative could be to use  [Query Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847184.aspx) and [raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to execute a raw SQL query and map it to a query type:

```
class FileAndSize
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public long Size {get;set;}
}


var files = myContext.Query<FileAndSize>
                     .FromSql("select name,datalength(file) as size from ...")
                     .Where(...)
                     .ToList();
```

Raw SQL queries can be combined with LINQ operators to create the final SQL statement, which allows adding `Where()`, `GroupBy` and other operators.

In EF Core versions before 2.1 it's still possible to execute raw SQL queries but they'll have to be mapped to entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Length` property of `Stream` class to get size, in bytes, of the current file:

```
long length;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    length = stream.Length;
}
```

[Please, read a description of `FileStream.Length` at MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.length?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets the length in bytes of the stream

**Update:**

If you use `EntityFramework`, then use `SqlFunctions`:

```
var fieldLength = yourContext.yourTable.Select(x => 
    new { Length = SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.B), A = x.A });
```

Comment: The database already provides that information. Opening 100s of files just get their length is very expensive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, it is very expensive, but OP wants to know how to do it. He already know how to achieve this through SQL query.

Comment: The way is `SELECT DataLength(Column)`. Whether that should be a raw SQL query or a mapped function call in EF is another matter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I’ eve added to the answer if you’ok with adding your character comment to a reply.